# jquery chosen, to update <option> fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-chosen

Have HTML:

```
<form id='country'>
<select id="region" name="region" class='chosen'>
   <?=$regions;?>
</select>
<br>
<select id="city" name="city" class='chosen'></select>
<br>
<select id="district" name="district" class='chosen'></select>
<br>
<select id="village" name="village" class='chosen'></select>
</form>
```

My optionsget content by Ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#region").on("change", function(){
    $(this).nextAll('select').html('');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.php",
        data: "ter_id="+$(this).val(),
        success:function(_ajax){
            $("#city").html(_ajax);
        }
    });
    $(this).trigger('chosen:updated'); //don't working, as like $("#country").trigger("liszt:updated")
})
```

What am I doing wrong? My options don't update after getting ajax-data. What and where need I to write?
chosen_v1.2.0.

Comment: are you not filling your `<select>`s with `<options`> on purpose? If you don't need the `<options>` why not just use a `<div>`?

Comment: No, I get options by ajax, look at my post.

Comment: This is only one handler function of three.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how chosen works but it needs to be triggered in the success callback. In your code, you're doing it way before the ajax response is available.

```
$(document).ready(function(){        
    $("#region").on("change", function(){
        var that = $(this);
        that.nextAll('select').html('');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "index.php",
            data: "ter_id="+that.val(),
            success:function(_ajax){
                $("#city").html(_ajax);
                that.trigger('chosen:updated'); <<=== HERE
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: What - "that" in line "that.trigger('chosen:updated');"?
Maybe, "this"?

Comment: Not sure I fully got you, but since `this` inside `success` is not the same as before the ajax, you would create a variable that would have a reference to the target element inside `success`. I have re-written your full snippet so you see how it fits in. (look up)?

Comment: You want to trigger `chosen` on the element that just changed.

Comment: Peterka,yeah, I've got u, was inattentive. Bit it does not work(

Comment: Can you provide a sample of `_ajax` -- what's returned by the ajax request?

Comment: String (set of options) and no more)
<option value="1224500000">some_cont</option>
<option value="1224800000">some_cont_2</option>
etc...

Answer (score 0):

I've got it. I just apply a chosen() method **in** success, after section filling.

```
$("#region").on("change", function(){
    var that = this;
    $(this).nextAll('select').html('').addClass('hidden');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.php",
        data: "ter_id="+$(this).val(),
        success:function(_ajax){
            $("#city").removeClass('hidden').attr('required','required').html(_ajax).chosen({'no_results_text': "Oops, nothing found!"});
        }
    });
})
```